# Resize display object and keep quality

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am learning Corona SDK and I need some help with something. I have a image that is rather big and I want to re-size it while still keeping the quality, I tried making an image that was the correct size but the quality wasn't that good.

Is there a way to re-size an image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a common solution:

```
local width= imageWidth;
local height = imageHeight;

myImage = display.newImage( "image.png", 0, 0)

local scaleFactor = newDesiredWidth / width

myImage.scaleX = scaleFactor
myImage.scaleY = scaleFactor
```

If you still don't like the quality then you should use a graphics editing program to resize your image. This way you will have two version: one for screens with higher resolution and the small one for smaller screens.

Also check this (Images part): http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/display-objects